# How to test if iframe exists with React testing library?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

In my React app I have a component which embeds an Instagram post.

It renders the following HTML structure:

```
<div data-testid="instagram"><iframe class="instagram-media instagram-media-rendered" id="instagram-embed-3" //etc....
```

I am using [React testing library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/).

How do I write a test that checks if the `iframe` element exists and e.g with the CSS class `instagram-media`?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For accessibility purposes, it is recommended to always use the `title` attribute on an `<iframe>` to label/describe its content.

```js
<div data-testid="instagram">
    <iframe title="Instagram embed" className="instagram-media ..." id="instagram-
embed-3"></iframe>
</div>
```

You can then test if the `<iframe>` element exists with the `getByTitle` query.

```js
expect(screen.getByTitle('Instagram embed')).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: note that `toBeInTheDocument()` requires `testing-library/jest-dom`

Comment: This just makes sure the title is there and is correct, it doesn't actually check that it's an iframe, or what its `src` attribute is, etc

Comment: @aarowman You can check what's in the `src` attribute with something like `expect(screen.getByTitle('Instagram embed')).toHaveAttribute('src', '<src-url>')`. Note that `toHaveAttribute` also requires `testing-library/jest-dom`.

Comment: @juliomalves Yes, I was pointing out that the accepted answer doesn't actually test the kind of element or attributes of it. It simply tests for the existence of a title, which could be on another element, or have other attributes (the answer is not fully complete). Your suggestion will help with `src`, and there is also more that could be added